# Google Doc and DropBox PHP api's

Tags: php, google-docs-api, dropbox-php

I want to add a list of all files from my google docs and from dropbox on my website(not a google site). The code of my website is mostly in PHP. I am unable to find a PHP guide for Google Docs list API and dropbox API. Any help is appreciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's Google APIs Client Library for PHP. [Link](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/)

You probably need to check this as well: [Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list)
There's a tab for PHP example

Answer (score 0):

[3rd Party Dropbox PHP SDK](https://github.com/BenTheDesigner/Dropbox) and [the Docs for the API generally](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api). You will specifically want to look into the [/metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#metadata) and [/files (GET)](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#files-GET) calls